# How to correctly add my new repository to github - repository not found

Tags: git, github, repository

Can anybody walk me through posting my new repository on Github?

I have tried to initialise git again in a folder different to the one I used before.

So I created a new folder on my Windows computer, My_tableau_projects. I have two files in it.

Then I ran

```
$ git init

$ git add . 
$ git commit -m "first commit"

$ git remote add origin https://github.com/bluetail14/My_Tableau_projects.git
error: remote origin already exists.
```

I think I have this error because at first I created a repository on github with the same name, but then I deleted it because I was not sure if I needed to create it first.

then I try

```
$ git branch -M main
$ git push -u origin main
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/bluetail14/My_Tableau_projects.git/' not found
```

So I am not sure how to proceed.. it says the repository already exists but then it says not found?

What would be the correct procedure for me to create a new repository on my github and move my files to it?

right now I have

```
$ git remote -v show
origin  https://github.com/bluetail14/My_Tableau_projects.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/bluetail14/My_Tableau_projects.git (push)
```

Comment: The answers below are good, but I wanted to mention my default workflow: I usually create the repo on GitHub via the browser interface, then do the operations you showed here and it works for me. But there are many good ways to do this, of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a new repository on GitHub using only the `git` commandline, for that you should use GitHub's own CLI: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create

```
gh repo create My_Tableau_projects
```

You can then set the origin of your repo to the github URL and push to it, essentially following the steps in [this article](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line) starting from step 8.

> - In the Command prompt, add the URL for the remote repository where your local repository will be pushed.
>
>   ```
>   $ git remote add origin  <REMOTE_URL> 
>   # Sets the new remote
>   $ git remote -v
>   # Verifies the new remote URL
>   ```
> - Push the changes in your local repository to GitHub.
>
>   ```
>   $ git push origin main
>   # Pushes the changes in your local repository up to the remote repository you specified as the origin
>   ```

Comment: bash: gh: command not found . guess its not possible to create one in Git Bash? wonder how hard it could be to install Github CLI...

Answer (score 1):

You have said that you deleted the repository in GitHub. Now you don't have the repository with the name "My_Tableau_projects". As far as I understood, you want to move your files into a GitHub repository.

For that, create a repository on GitHub in the GitHub website itself as it is not possible to create a repo in GitHub directly from the command line. If you are using Git Bash, first initialize git in that folder from which you want to upload the files into your GitHub repository that you created.

Command to initialize git: `git init`

Then enter the command line `git add -A` to include the files that are to be committed.

Then commit to included files by entering the command line `git commit -m "first commit"`.

Currently, the initialized git in your local machine is in the branch `master`. But in GitHub, the repo you have created has the active branch `main`.

To make the branch in your machine as main, enter the command line `git branch -M main`.

Now, enter the command line `git remote add origin https://github.com/bluetail14/My_Tableau_projects.git`.

Lastly, push your included files into the github repo that you have created, by entering the command line `git push -u origin main`.

Comment: thank you! I wonder what '-M' mean?  I thought it means message but it does not make sense here.

Comment: We are basically renaming the branch. There even `-m` would work. Another way of renaming the branch is `git branch -m <oldname> <newname>`. The easier one is `git branch -m <newname>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have deleted the Github repository, so now in Github the repository no longer exists. My workflow for creating a project is:

First I create a folder locally in my machine `git init` and then I got to github and add it following its workflow.

Comment: I would delete both repositories (local and online) and start a new one since you don't have anything